# How do I stop the HTML tags from being stripped out in this XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This generates XML for posting to a job board. I did not come up with the system and don't know very much about XSLT. But for some reason, the HTML tags like `<h3>` are getting stripped out of the description text which breaks the formatting and makes the post on the job board look a mess.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent this from happening:

the problem is specifically this bit:

```
<member>
  <name>description</name>
  <value>
    <xsl:value-of select="job_intro" />
    <xsl:value-of select="location_description" />
    <xsl:value-of select="job_description" />
    <xsl:value-of select="brand_desc" />
  </value>
</member>
```

The `xsl:value-of select="location_description"` for example is stripping out the html formatting and I want to keep it in.

Here is the full thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

    <xsl:param name="transaction"/>
    <xsl:param name="adtype"/>
    <xsl:param name="testmode"/>
    <xsl:param name="username"/>
    <xsl:param name="password"/>

    <xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>

    <xsl:output method = "xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="pb_ad">
        <xsl:if test="$transaction!='DELETE'">
            <methodCall>
                <methodName>submitJob</methodName>
                <params>
                    <param><value><struct>
                                <member><name>source</name><value><i4>76</i4></value></member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>username</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <string>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                
                                            </xsl:choose>


                                        </string>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>password</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <string>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </string>
                                    </value>
                                </member>

                                <member><name>reference</name><value><i4><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>title</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="headline"/></string></value></member>
                                

                       
                                <member><name>industry</name><value><i4>27</i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>type</name><value><string>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="employment_term_id=2">contract</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="employment_term_id=5">temporary</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="employment_term_id=6">part_time</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>permanent</xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </string></value></member>
                                <member><name>salary_min</name><value><i4><xsl:value-of select="salaryfrom"/></i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>salary_max</name><value><i4><xsl:value-of select="salaryto"/></i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>salary_period</name><value><i4>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="pay_period_id=2">405</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="pay_period_id=3">406</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="pay_period_id=4">407</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="pay_period_id=5">404</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>403</xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>salary_info</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="job_salary"/></string></value></member>
                                <member><name>region</name><value><i4><xsl:value-of select="locations_mapped/location"/></i4></value></member>
                                <member><name>display_location</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="hotel"/></string></value></member>
                                <member><name>precise_location</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="postcode"/></string></value></member>
                                <member><name>description</name><value><xsl:value-of select="job_intro" /><xsl:value-of select="location_description" /><xsl:value-of select="job_description" /><xsl:value-of select="brand_desc" /></value></member>

                                <xsl:if test="apply_online_url!=''">
                                    <member><name>external_url</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="apply_online_url"/></string></value></member>
                                    <member><name>contact_name</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="contact_first_name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="contact_last_name"/></string></value></member>
                                    <member><name>contact_telephone</name><value><string></string></value></member>
                                    <member><name>contact_email</name><value><string></string></value></member>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="apply_online_url=''">
                                    <member><name>contact_name</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="contact_first_name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="contact_last_name"/></string></value></member>
                                    <member><name>contact_telephone</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="contact_work_phone"/></string></value></member>
                                    <member><name>contact_email</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="email"/></string></value></member>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <member><name>direct_apply_url</name><value><string></string></value></member>
                                <member><name>direct_apply_jobid</name><value><string><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></string></value></member>
                                <member><name>all_industries</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member>
                            </struct></value>
                    </param>
                </params>
            </methodCall>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please add the XML sample code as well.

Comment: There is none. All i know is HTML gets passed in from the database to the value-of tags in the description

Comment: If you are unable to provide the xml-source of i.e. location_description there is nobody who can really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#value-of) will give you the computed text value of the selected node.

If you want to preserve the markup, then should use [`xsl:copy-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-copy-of), which will perform a deep copy and avoid atomization and "flattening" of the markup into a text() node that is being done with `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: I tried that and it generated new tags like <job_description> which is not what I need. I need the HTML to be inside the <description> tag

Comment: then you may need to transform your data, pushing the source nodes through some templates - but that is a different problem. You wanted to know why the HTML elements were being stripped in your output, and the reason is because you are using value-of which strips the elements and returns the "stringified" value.

Comment: Without seeing the input and desired output, it is more difficult to provide advice - but if you want the contents of `<job_description>` and not the element itself, then use `<xsl:copy-of select="job_description/node()"/>`

Comment: the html tags are still getting stripped

Comment: are you sure that they aren't being stripped by the process consuming your output (sanitizing it before rendering)?